# How do I code a String value that has to have 3 or more characters?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to place a limit on the amount of characters used in a String but, I can't seem to figure out how to code that if, for example I say 'He' instead of 'Hello' I want my code to show an error because 'He' contains less than 3 characters. Any suggestions?

```
package trial;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trial {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
                String word = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("The Word you have typed is: " + word);
```

Comment: Use `String#split()` and `String#length()`.

Comment: `String.length()`...

Comment: thank you for your help :) String.length() word perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is good just let the user keep entering the value until the characters more than 3 so you do that by while loop that check the number of word's characters

```
package trial;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trial {


public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            String word="";
            while(word.length()<3){     

                System.out.println("Enter a word with more or equals to 3 characters: ");

                 word = input.nextLine();
            }  
                    System.out.println("The Word you have typed is: " + word);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. With this, "Enter word...." will keep repeating until the user types more than 3 characters. Thank you for the extra input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only alphanumeric characters you can use a regex with `\w` and leverage **[String.matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))** like:

```
String word = input.nextLine();

// Validates word is 3 or more characters long
if (!word.matches("\\w{3,}")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word must have 3 or more characters");
}
System.out.println("The Word you have typed is: " + word);
```

Another regex ideas might be:

```
[\w\s]{3,} --> alphanumeric and spaces with 3 or more
```

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the `Strings` length to see if it is less than 3...

```
if(word.length() < 3)
{
    System.err.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added it to my code and works perfectly :)

Comment: Who downvotes the correct answer? Speak up a downvote doesn't do anyone any good unless you say why...

Comment: Was an accident, sorry!